# How to query mySQL to a HTML page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I'm working on an HTML page that shows order statistics from a mysql database. However my javascript function calls aren't modifying the html page.

I have tried adding  in the head tag to call the functions from my index.js file. Whenever I google this, most people use PHP, however I am trying to keep complexity to a minimum and would like to do so without PHP if I can. I am able to query the database just fine with my javascript code, and get the expected output in the terminal. However, I can't figure out how to display that same console output to my web page.

```
const con = require('./connection.js');



function dessertsOrdered() {
    con.query("SELECT MAX(ordered_dessert_id) FROM ordered_dessert", function (err, result, fields) {
        var value = console.log(result);
        //document.write(value);
     });

}
//document.write(entreesOrdered());
dessertsOrdered();
```

the following is my extremely basic html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> This is the heading 
    <script type="text\javascript" src="connection.js"> </script>
    <script type="text\javascript" src="index.js"> </script>


    <title>abc</title><meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <style> 
    h2 {
        color: rgb(0, 232, 15)

    }
    body {
        background-color: gray;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Manager stats</h1>
<h2>Burgers sold</h2>
<h2>Drinks sold</h2>
<h2>Sides sold</h2>
<h2>Desserts sold</h2>
<script>(burgersOrdered());</script>
<h2>Total Orders</h2>
<h2>Revenue sold</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

the index.js file, when run in terminal using `node index.js` outputs:

> [ RowDataPacket { 'MAX(ordered_dessert_id)': 25 } ]

meaning it accessed the database and got 25 orders for desserts. I want to display this to the web browser.

Comment: Connecting database should be done on the backend side. The fact you were able to run `node index.js` means that `index.js` is a script to run a node server.

Comment: The JS you run on the page should be different to the JS you run on the server. You'll need to use AJAX to send a request from the page to the server, and then get the result back. Check out [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Okay, thank you! I will research AJAX. I knew I was doing something wrong.